# How update a table in codeigniter with inner join?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I want to convert this query Mysql in Query Builder Codeigniter

The query is works in mysql but don't works in codeigniter

Mysql

```
UPDATE tbl_person p
INNER JOIN tbl_family_victim f  ON  p.id_person = f.id_person
SET p.active = 0
WHERE f.id_prisoners = 32;
```

Codeigniter

```
public function delete_all($id_pris){
   $this->db->join('tbl_family f','p.id_person = f.id_person');
   $this->db->set('p.active', '0');
   $this->db->where('f.id_prisoners', $id_pris);
   $data_result = $this->db->update('tbl_person p');
   return  $data_result;
}
```

Comment: You have errors in your sql query. https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: check this link, it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323649/update-and-join-query-together-in-codeigniter/42323687

Comment: I put in practice this link that you show me, but don't ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have minute error in your script, you missed alias of slave table

**VERSION 1**

```
public function delete_all($id_pris){
   $this->db->join('tbl_family f','p.id_person = f.id_person',"inner"); // you missed `f` here
   $this->db->set('p.active', '0');
   $this->db->where('f.id_prisoners', $id_pris);
   $data_result = $this->db->update('tbl_person p');
   return  $data_result;
}
```

This should work fine.

**VERSION 2**

```
$this->db->set('p.active', '0');
$this->db->where('f.id_prisoners', $id_pris);
$this->db->where('p.id_person = f.id_person')
$data_result = $this->db->update('tbl_family as f, tbl_person as p');
return $data_result;
```

**VERSION 3**

```
$sql = "
UPDATE tbl_person p
INNER JOIN tbl_family_victim f  ON  p.id_person = f.id_person
SET p.active = 0
WHERE f.id_prisoners = $id_pris";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

**VERSION 4**

```
$this->db->set('p.active', '0');
$this->db->where('f.id_prisoners', $id_pris);
$data_result = $this->db->update('tbl_family as f JOIN  tbl_person as p ON p.id_person = f.id_person');
return $data_result;
```

Comment: sorry my friend, don't works! Do you have another idea?

Comment: Check all versions of my updated answer. It must work now.

Comment: Thank my friend!! The **ANSWER** is in VERSION 3 !! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function delete_all($id_pris){
   $this->db->set('p.active', '0');
   $this->db->where('f.id_prisoners', $id_pris);
   $data_result = $this->db->update('tbl_person p JOIN tbl_family f ON p.id_person = f.id_person');
   return  $data_result;
}
```